# Remote debug ec2 java instance

Tags: java, debugging, amazon-ec2

My application is running in EC2 as a docker with java application. 
I'm exposing 5005 port for debug, and locally it works perfectly. However on EC2 environment I get 
`java.net.ConnectException "Connection refused (Connection refused)"`
when trying to connect using Intelij.

- Security group is set to open ports 80, 5005, 22
- Docker is exposing port 80 and 5005
- Application is running with java args
  `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=5005,suspend=n`

Am I missing something ?

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you are trying to connect via port 5005 and you get a connection refused, how are you trying to coonect to that EC2 instance, is it via a gateway or directly via a public IP?

Comment: Directly via a public IP. Port 5005 is open. Connecting to application via http (80) and ssh (22) goes without any problems. Debugging this app as local goes without any problem as well. It's occur when I'm trying to connect when the app is behind EC2 VM and docker

Comment: Did you get the solution to this? If you get, please post it in answer section.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still interested, here is a way how to create a Remote JVM Debug on EC2 with docker

1. On the yaml file add the 'port' attribute.

> ```
>  ports:
>      - "5005:5005"
> ```

2. To the dockerfile run the Jar with the following command

> ```
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
> ```

3. On the inbound role on the EC2:

> ```
> Cutsom TCP => 5005 => Your IP
> ```

4. In the Intellij create Remote JVM debug

   - In the host enter the host ip
   - Port: 5005
   - Choose JDK 9 or later as the address should be with *:5005
5. Click the Debug Button and it should work